# Cannot expand Microsoft Exchange On-Premises

Tags: exchange-server-2010

I installed Microsoft Exchange 2010 SP3 on Windows Server 2008 R2 successfully but when I try to expand the **Microsoft Exchange On-Premises** the initialization fails with the error

Initialization Failed
The following error occurred when retrieving user information for 'Domain\User': The operation could not be performed because `Domain\User` could not be found.

Initially I thought it to be the issue related to [KB982639](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/981033) but that doesn't seems to fit here, other then this I have no clue to what the issue could be.

Any lead is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, such issue is probably due to the same SID of the domain machines or the AD/DC and one of the machine or all of the three. For me when I faced this issue the problem was that I cloned all the 3 machines from the VM Template and did not run `sysprep` properly which caused the conflict. As the AD recognizes the machines from SID it couldn't recognize the machine and this could not retrieve the user information causing the "Initialization Failed".

**Solution**
Run sysprep on all the 3 machines with `generalize` option checked. `sysprep` can be found in `C:\Windows\System32\sysprep\`. Unfortunately, you have to destroy the current setup you have as you have messed up with the user info in Active Directory.